# How can I create a popup box with arrow with a box shadow also?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have managed to get a popup box like this with box shadow but it looks incorrect and the arrow looks like a rhombus on the edge. how can I make it bigger and just a triangle on the side like this. Needs a box shadow too

[image]

```css
.audio-arrow-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 284px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.audio-arrow-box::after {
  z-index: -99;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: calc(25% - 5px);
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.audio-arrow-box::before {
  z-index: 10;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: calc(25% - 5px);
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-arrow-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily solve the shape problem, but you can use [`filter: drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) to get a single shadow on the entire element instead of having a separate one for the arrow.

```css
.audio-arrow-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: block;

  /* replaced box-shadow with filter */
  filter: drop-shadow(0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));

  width: 284px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.audio-arrow-box::after {
  z-index: -99;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: calc(25% - 5px);
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);

  /* removed box-shadow rule */
}

.audio-arrow-box::before {
  z-index: 10;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: calc(25% - 5px);
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff #fff;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="audio-arrow-box"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? [https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) It looks like the question you linked to is talking about a problem with a scale transform in addition to the filter.

Comment: Works for me in Safari. [https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/t6nhqxmf/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/t6nhqxmf/2/)

Comment: [This screenshot](https://d.pr/i/nP6QWZ) is from my answer, on this page, in Safari. So either it works in Safari or I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: [Still works for me in Safari](https://d.pr/i/9EVn0S), transform or not. And you can see that it works in my snippet above, right? Have *you* tried it in Safari?